Storing and Retrieving RGB with SwiftData
I am out of ideas. I am trying to have a color theme picker in a view that would allow selection of predefined color theme values, store it in SwiftData as persistent storage and then use it throughout the app.
I have this model to store values for Red Green and Blue:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class SettingsModel {
    
    var red: CGFloat
    var green: CGFloat
    var blue: CGFloat
    
    init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) {
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
    }
}

I reference it in my App root view:
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
    .modelContainer(for: SettingsModel.self)
}

In the actual view I define an array of color themes with custom RGB values that can be selected in the Picker. In the onChange of the Picker I can see the actual color values with color.red, color.green, color.blue but when I want to see what is inside the model with the List then they are all 0:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct SettingsView: View {

    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    @Query private var colorTheme: [SettingsModel]
    
    @State private var selectedColor: String = "Theme 1"
    
    struct RGBColor {
        let red: CGFloat
        let green: CGFloat
        let blue: CGFloat
    }

    let colorThemes: [String: RGBColor] = [
        "Theme 1": RGBColor(red: 0, green: 199, blue: 190),
        "Theme 2": RGBColor(red: 50, green: 173, blue: 230),
        "Theme 3": RGBColor(red: 88, green: 86, blue: 214),
    ]
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Color Theme", selection: $selectedColor) {
                ForEach(Array(colorThemes.keys), id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name).tag(name)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedColor) {
                if let color = colorThemes[selectedColor] {
                   context.insert(SettingsModel(red: color.red, green: color.green, blue: 
                   color.blue))
                }
            }
        List(colorTheme) { color in
            Text("R: \(String(format: "%.2f", color.red)), G: \(String(format: "%.2f", 
                 color.green)), B: \(String(format: "%.2f", color.blue))")
            }
        }
    }
}

I am not getting any errors, just 0 data in the store after context.insert().

CGFloat is a special type and it might not be supported by SwiftData yet, try using Double instead as the type for your properties

@JoakimDanielson, thanks for quick reply. I first tried with Color but then found out that SwiftData is still quite limited, never thought that I need to go with true primitives. I'll try that. Thanks!

You can of course use computed properties that returns CGFloat or even a single computed property that returns RGBColor if you want to simplify the usage of SettingsModel

@JoakimDanielson quickly changed all CGFloat types to Double and now I see the values in store. Thank you for the solution!

You should post your implementation as an answer or delete the question so it isn't left hanging.
